# Roll back transaction and close connection on thrown exceptions

Tags: hibernate, ejb, ejb-3.0

Currently in my JavaEE application-server with local and remote EJB's, MDB's (Singleton and Stateless) I am using JDBC-Transactions for Hibernate Core.

Managing myself all my opening and closing, committing of hibernate sessions and transactions can lead to connection-leaks and uncomitted transactions.
Especially in the case of programming errors resulting in custom or unchecked exceptions that are not catched and thrown to the remote client.

What is the easiest or best way to make sure my hibernate sessions are closed and transactions rolled back in case an error is thrown?

Use container-managed transactions (CMT) or is it possible to close sessions within an interceptor that is called on return of any EJB methods?

*One easy way would be to wrap the session-scoped usage in a try-catch block and catching any type of Exception, but a general approach with less code would be favored.*

**Edit: Remote EJB Example**

- My low-level Hibernate DAO does closes connection and rolls back transaction on thrown exceptions. Problematic is business-logic between DAO accesses in case connection is still open.*

  ```
  public void doSomething(Foo foo) throws Exception
  {
      // open session and transaction
      Session session = DAO.openSession();

      // retrieve data
      Bar bar = DAO.get(session, ...) 

      // call other methods which throws an exception resulting in open connection
      doOtherStuff(foo, bar)

      DAO.save(session, foo);

      // commit transaction
      DAO.closeAndCommitSession(session);
  }
  ```

Right now i am using a big try-catch-finally:

```
    public void doSomething(Foo foo) throws Exception
    {
        // open session and transaction
        Session session = DAO.openSession();
        try
        {
            // retrieve data
            Bar bar = DAO.get(session, ...) 

            // call other methods which throws an exception resulting in open connection
            doOtherStuff(foo, bar)

            DAO.save(session, foo);
        }
        catch (final Exception e)
        {
            DAO.rollBackTransaction(session);
            throw e;
        }
        finally
        {
            DAO.closeAndCommitSession(session);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally speaking this question is about doing **resource management** *correctly* and in a *simple* way. This always requires two ingredients: A simple API and discipline to use this API everywhere.

Probably not a concrete solution for your use case using Hibernate, but just to show the general idea: Use the **loan pattern**:

```
public interface ConnectionRunnable {
    public void run(Connection conn) throws SQLException;
}
```

This code would be far more elegant, if you used Groovy or Scala (with closures). In that case this interface is not needed.

Anyway, everywhere you need a connection, use something like this:

```
    public static void withConnection(final String dataSourceName,
            ConnectionRunnable runnable) throws SQLException, NamingException {
        final InitialContext ic = new InitialContext();
        final DataSource ds = (DataSource) ic.lookup(dataSourceName);

        final Connection conn = ds.getConnection();
        try {
            runnable.run(conn);
        } finally {
            conn.close();
        }
    }
```

to be used like this in your EJBs:

```
ConnectionUtils.withConnection("java:/jdbc/sandbox", new ConnectionRunnable() {
    public void run(Connection conn) throws SQLException {
        // Do something with the connection
    }
});
```

- Using the loan pattern, you simply can't forget to close a connection
- In case of a `SQLException` or `NamingException` you can **centrally** decide how to handle it **correctly**: commit or rollback manually using BMT. Use `setRollbackOnly` or throw a `SystemException` to trigger the container (using CMT) etc. If there is no special reason, use CMT.
- Even if you change your error handling later, it's only one code fragment.

---

Update: Overhead of using the `ConnectionRunnable` interface.

The `ConnectionRunnable` is a "typing-overhead" only: Groovy and Scala implement closures the same way, and the run-time overhead is negligible. Java 8 will implement closures probably the same way.

In this scenario the costs of committing or rolling back on a database transaction will be much higher anyway.

It's just looking odd from the Java/procedural/usual perspective, and the idea of code reuse with respect to exception handling may look odd as well.

Using Scala it looks like this at the usage site (translated literally):

```scala
ConnectionUtils.withConnection("java:/jdbc/sandbox") {
  conn =>
    // Do something with the connection
}
```

but under the hood it uses something like an anonymous class on the JVM as well .

Comment: This would need a `ConnectionRunnable` for each method which seems like very big overhead. Closing connections is the lowest priority since this is just a programming error. More problematic are uncatched exceptions which will be thrown to client while connection is still open and transaction not rolled back.

Comment: @djmj: The solution proposed by Beryllium seems concise and elegant, even if it requires an anonymous inner class for each connection.  The beauty here is that it allows you to -both- manage resources and handle exceptions in a more deterministic way.  Am I missing something?

Comment: @scottb Nice summary! I just like to add that you need fewer lines of code at the usage site: The nested exception handling clutters up the code otherwise at every usage site.

Comment: @djmj: I have updated the answer. If Java 8 is available, the functional style will probably look less odd, because of a better syntax, and it will probably used all over the place.

Comment: I see the good point of this pattern for the most basic data access layer in case Connection or a few others are the only necessary parameters. But as soon as business-logic happens within the methods which needs several other parameters or access to other members and methods the typing overhead is huge. I cannot create an interface for each possible use-case. I updated my answer on a simplified use-case. I think i will have a look at CMT. I hoped for something like an annotated method (like `@PreDestroy`) that is called right before any ejb method returns.

Comment: Your simplified use case could be handled the proposed way. Could you add another example which couldn't be dealt with in that way? I do not see too many resources here: Looking at JDBC it is: withConnection, withResultSet, withPreparedStatement, withCallableStatement. Another option (annotated method): Have a look at EJB interceptors: [@Interceptors, @AroundInvoke](http://www.byteslounge.com/tutorials/java-ee-ejb-interceptors-tutorial-and-example).